# Prove that $C(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $C(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of continuous bounded functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and the metric $d(f,g) = \text{sup}_{t\in\mathbb{R}}|f-g|$.

Prove that $C(\mathbb{R})$ is not separable.

May I know if my proof is correct?

Let $A=$ set of all continuous tent functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ such that $f(n) = 0$ or $1,$ if $n$ is natural number. Then $\{f_{\restriction_{\mathbb{N}}}: f \in A \}$ has same cardinality as $2^{\mathbb{N}}$, so $A$ is uncountable.

Now, given $f, g\in A, d(f,g) = 1$ and $B(f,0.3) \cap B(g,0.3) = \emptyset$ whenever $f\neq g$. Why? Suppose there exists $h\in B(f,0.3) \cap B(g,0.3),$ then $1= d(f,g) \leq d(f,h) + d(h,g) < 0.6. $ Contradiction.

Since there are uncountably many such balls and if there exists a dense subset of $C(\mathbb{R}),$ it must intersect uncountably many such balls. Contradiction.

Thank you.

Comment: I can’t make heads or tails of your proof to be completely honest.

Comment: Perhaps you can make the idea work, but as is it is not sufficient for a proof. Functions in your set are not continuous, so they can not provide a counterexample themselves, you have to modify them, using [bump functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) perhaps. It is unclear where the ball in $B(f,0.5) = \{f\}$ is taken, and there are certainly continuous functions within $0.5$ sup distance of your $f$ other than $f$ itself.

Comment: Dear Confiold, I am really grateful for your kind words. I have amended my proof. Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 3):

Right general thrust, but you're being too lazy/sloppy in the details.

I think you should define $A$ in more detail. As it stands, the "set of piecewise continuous functions bounded by $1$ such that $f(n) = 0$ or $1$ if $n$ is a natural number" does not produce the isolated points that you claim later in the proof. As written, for any $\varepsilon \in (0, 1)$, you would have
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } |x| \ge \varepsilon \\ 1 - x/\varepsilon & \text{if }0 \le x < \varepsilon \\ 1 + x/\varepsilon & \text{if } -\varepsilon<x<0,\end{cases}$$
as this function is continuous everywhere, and $f(n) \in \{0, 1\}$ for all natural numbers $n$. Note that these functions do not remain distance at least $1/2$ from each other!

Further, I think rather than "piecewise continuous", you mean "piecewise linear", and simply restricting to the natural numbers means all sorts of shenanigans can occur on the negative real axis (and, as I was trying to demonstrate above, between the integers too).

You also write $\{f(\mathbb{N}): f \in \mathbb{N}\}$, which doesn't make sense. I presume you meant to write $\{f(\mathbb{N}): f \in A\}$, but even then, $f(\Bbb{N})$ can only equal $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, or $\{0, 1\}$ by assumption. What you really want is $A$ to be uncountable, and you want to show it's uncountable by injecting into it a known uncountable set, presumably the power set of the natural numbers.

Another small issue is that an uncountable number of balls is not quite enough to show inseparability. You need to show that the balls are pairwise disjoint. For example, in $\Bbb{R}$, the sets $\{(-a, a) : a \in \Bbb{R}\}$ are uncountable, but $\Bbb{R}$ is still separable.

So, you should define more rigorously exactly which functions are contained in $A$, and show more precisely that $A$ is uncountable. Here's the way I'd do it:

Define a map $\phi : \mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N}) \to \{0, 1\}^\Bbb{N}$ by
$$\phi(S) : n \mapsto \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } n \in S \\ 0 & \text{if } n \notin S. \end{cases}$$
Show that this map is injective. Then, for any $S$, define the function
$$f_S(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x < 0 \\ \phi(S)(x) & \text{if } x \in \Bbb{N} \\ (x - \lfloor x \rfloor)\phi(S)(\lfloor x \rfloor) + (\lceil x \rceil - x)\phi(S)(\lceil x \rceil) & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$
Proving its bounded by $1$ is straightforward enough. Continuity is a little less straight forward; you can show it without much difficulty for $x \notin \Bbb{N}$, as it is locally equal to a linear polynomial. For $x \in \Bbb{N}$, you'll have to do a left and right limit argument.

You also need to show that $S \mapsto f_S$ is injective, and thus conclude that $\{f_S : S \subseteq \Bbb{N}\}$ is uncountable. Finally, you need to show that $S_1 \neq S_2 \implies \|f_{S_1} - f_{S_2}\|_\infty \ge 1$, so that the balls of radius $1/2$ fail to intersect. This should be easy enough: look for a point $n$ in $S_1$ but not in $S_2$, or vice-versa, and compute $|f_{S_1}(n) - f_{S_2}(n)|$.

So, there's a bit of work to do. It's ok to gloss over this work when a) you understand exactly what you're glossing over and how you'd write out the details, and b) when the reader would not be interested and could fill in the tedious details themself. The errors in your write-up suggest to me that a) does not apply to you, and you should write out the details.

Answer (score 1):

With the additional condition of "tent function", this seems to work.

---

edit for your second proof:

(i) The new idea is to find an uncountable collection of disjoints open subsets of $\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$. A dense subset would then intersect all of these open subsets, hence has uncountable cardinal. I believe this is true.

How ever the collection of subsets you chose doesn't work, because:

(ii)

> Now, given $f,g\in A,d(f,g)=1$

Here are two functions $f,g\in A$ with the distance $d(f,g)$<1. It can be done for any $\varepsilon>0$.

[image]

(iii) The other answer gives a detailed construction of such a collection of open subsets, given by $\{B_{1/2}(f_S), S\subset\mathbb{N}\}$. Of course there exist other such collections.

---

(i) $B(f,0.5)$ surely contains elements different from $f$. We can choose such element inside the set $A$.

[image]

(ii) Your idea is to find isolated points and to use them to prove separability.

(a) There is no isolated point in $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$: choose any $\varepsilon>0$ and a function $f$. Then $f+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ is another function different from $f$ and contained in the ball $B(f,\varepsilon)$.

(b) Suppose $X$ is a metric space with uncountably many isolated points. Then any dense subset have to contain all these isolated points. Hence $X$ is not separable. This works!

I suggest that you find another method to apply to $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R})$, and that you note down your idea on isolated points somewhere for further usage.

Comment: Dear Learning, thank you for your kind comments. I have amended my proof accordingy.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo I edited my answer. Don't forget to upvote ;).

Comment: Dear Learning, but $A$ require $f,g$ to be tent functions.

Comment: Excuse me, I missed that. Will update my answer.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo I think you made it :) However you should write it more clearly, according to your professor/course standard.

Comment: Noted on the valuable input. I have read your suggestion in detail and it is illuminating. To be honest, I did not read the comment by the user 754697 in detail..

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo the proof by user754697 is the next step to be sure that everything works correctly. Intuitively I can tell you that your idea works, but I cannot be sure. I would have to write down some set-theoretic proof (of injectivity, to prove that the cardinal of your set is indeed uncountable; the balls don't intersect;...) to check it. And these set-theoretic arguments will be the kind of those given in the answer of user754697. His idea is quite the same as yours, but his collection of open sets is different, and perhaps less intuitive to you.

Comment: Noted. Also, if I allow $C(\mathbb{R})$ to contain unbounded continuous functions, will this problem make sense?

Comment: For unbounded functions, the $\sup$ is not necessarily finite. You'll have to find another distance.